# Changing non-numeric "nan" values in a numpy array: Name not defined error

Tags: python, arrays, for-loop

I have a numpy array containing a series of observations, but some values are missing and as such defined as nan. I want to convert these values to zero. The code:

```
for i in range(len(data)):
    if data[i]==nan:
        data[i]=0
```

However Python outputs:

```
NameError: name 'nan' is not defined
```

If I use "", no error is displayed, but the values are not changed. What do I need to do in order to make this for loop work?

Comment: hav you tried `from numpy import nan`

Comment: @Surajano no, but I would like to know why this method outputs the error and how to change any non-numeric vales...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the `isnan` function present in numpy. After you `import numpy`, do this:

```
for i in range(len(data)):
    if numpy.isnan(data[i]):
        data[i]=0
```